# Subdomain point to subfolder (WITHOUT REDIRECT)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have googled all day long and I cant get this right. I have the following rule in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.domain.com/site/%1/$1 [L]
```

What this code does is as following

Visit: ***subsite.domain.com/contact-us***
It will redirect you to ***app.domain.com/site/subsite/contact-us***

This is what I want BUT i dont want an actual redirect. So when I browse this "subsite" I always wanna have **subsite.domain.com**/[something...]

I have read that removing the domain name from the RewriteRule will fix it. But it doesnt work...

Is this possible with just htaccess rules?

Comment: I have an managed server so i have control of everything I guess? The thing the is important is this needs to be dynamic. I most be able to create a new "subsite" without editing options on the server or htaccess.

Comment: ok then how did you create subsite? Can you show it's `VirtualHost` entry?

Comment: Oh no, u miss understood me.  My site lets users create their own (basic) site, with help of php and mysql. So the pages is just pure text.
If you visit http://app.domain.com/site/username/constact-us it will look up in the database if that username exits.

Comment: You cannot create subdomains out of thin air like that. Valid DNS entry mist exist for each subdomain.

Comment: Daaaarn! So the only solution to this to add new entires for each subdomain in the vhost file? Ty for your clarification atleast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the only solution to this to add new entires for each subdomain in
>   the vhost file?

That's not entirely accurate.

You can create wildcard subdomains so that any subdomain will be accepted. 
In DNS for your domain name **add a subdomain** called `*`.

```
*.example.com 192.168.1.1
```

Then in your apache vhost file below `ServerName` add a new `serveralias` line or add it to the existing `serveralias`.

```
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

Then in your .htaccess file try using a **proxy** using the `P flag` because your can't use a different domain name in rewrite or it will do a redirect as you have found out. Ensure `mod_proxy` is enabled in apache. It usually is. Then your app can handle the requested folders.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://app.domain.com/site/%1/$1 [P]
```

Comment: If you use cPanel you can create a wildcard vhost by adding a subdomain with * then point the subdomain to a folder of your choice.

Comment: Hi Panama! I actually made it work thanks to you! Sorry for not replying.