# Create wildcard subdomain using htaccess in wordpress for different shop users

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to create wildcard sub-domains for each user shop using htaccess or any other methodology. But I don't want to create sub-domain folders.

For ex I have URL like:

```
https://example.com/wbb/john
```

and want this URL to become

```
https://john.example.com
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Subdomain point to subfolder (WITHOUT REDIRECT)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32486597/subdomain-point-to-subfolder-without-redirect)

Comment: No, this is not what I am asking. My requirement is to have subdomain without creating and pointing the wildcard to any other folder instead of root (public_html) folder

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
In your DNS, set *.domain.tld to point to your server. Then in your CP set *.domain.tld to point to a folder.

Now, in notepad or something create a file named index.php, inside that file add this:

```
<?php
$UserSubdomain = array_shift((explode(".",$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])));

if($UserSubdomain==TRUE){

    header("Location: http://example.com/wbb/$UserSubdomain");
}

else{

    header("Location: http://example.com/user-not-found");
}
```

Now, save the file and upload it to the folder.

This will NOT make the url be `john.example.com` but it will send `john.example.com` to `http://example.com/wbb/john`

Comment: Should I need to create folder for subdomain as well?

Comment: do you use cPanel for hosting ?

Comment: Yes I am using cpanel. I have created *.domain.com and it points to root folder.

Comment: Point it to another folder, for example: instead of public_html to wildcard

Comment: "This will NOT make the url be john.example.com but it will send john.example.com to http://example.com/wbb/john"

This functionality is currently working. I need to make the url to become http://john.domain.com